# client can not connect againt to my Socket Server - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I have a thread and a socket server for listening to client. Client software is not for me and it is a Laboratory Software that sends data to my program.

when listening starts there is no problem but when the client software is closed and reopened, that can not send any data to my software.

My listener must be run every time like a service.

This is my code:

```
Delegate Sub WriteMsgHandle(ByVal Msg As String)
Dim handler As WriteMsgHandle

Dim THS As ThreadStart
Dim TH As Thread
Private Sub btnListen_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnListen.Click
    Try
        btnListen.Enabled = False

        THS = New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listen)
        TH = New Thread(THS)
        TH.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
Public Sub Listen()
    Dim bytesReceived As Integer = 0
    Dim recv() As Byte = New Byte(1) {}
    Dim clientSocket As Socket
    Dim listenerSocket As New Socket _
        (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    Dim IPHost As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim localadd As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(txt_ip.Text)
    Dim ipepServer As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(localadd, txt_port.Text)
    handler = AddressOf WriteMsg
    listenerSocket.Bind(ipepServer)
    listenerSocket.Listen(-1)
    clientSocket = listenerSocket.Accept()

    Dim msgcount As Integer = 0

    If clientSocket.Connected Then

        MsgBox("Connected")

        Do
            bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(recv)
            Dim Msg As String

            Msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv)
            Invoke(handler, Msg)

        Loop While bytesReceived <> 0

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're only accepting once. You need to accept in a loop.
2. `If clientSocket.Connected Then` why did you add this? Delete that check. The socket was just accepted so it is connected. Even if it was disconnected do you want to just ignore that error condition?!
3. The receive loop is correct.
4. You probably want to start each accepted client on a new thread (or use async IO).

Comment: thanks, but i need to know when received data from client was ended to send for it a string. how can i know?